# how to apply AND operator horizontally on rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table has 5 columns (ID,UserId,Question and Answer, WebEnabled).

"UserId" is a FK and this table actually resolve multivalued attribute issue.

Here is sample data:

```
Id  UserId  Question    Answer  WebEnabled
1   1   Q1              Ans1    1
2   1   Q2              Ans2    1
3   2   Q1              Ans1    1
4   2   Q4              Ans4    1
5   3   Q1              Ans1    1
6   3   Q3              Ans3    1
7   3   Q2              Ans2    0
8   4   Q5              Ans5    0
```

I need to do search functionality with AND operator.

For example user entered Q1 and Q2 from web drop downs will need to return all userId which has Q1 and Q2 in Questions.

Help please.

**Edit:**

Q1, Q2 can be any number of parameters (say Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4) and query should use all of them with AND and return the UserID.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question. The statement below will get the answer you have asked for but it seems that maybe this is not what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserId
FROM   Table
WHERE  Question='Q1'
       OR
       Question='Q2'
```

Comment: can you please see my edit

Comment: OK, where is the data coming from and how is it getting to SQL Server?

Comment: There are two more tables. 1st Having questions definations and second having possible answers of each question. This table has chosen answer with question.

Comment: Can you add the table schemas and sample data for these please?

Comment: Thanks a lot Dale M for your previous time and attention. I really highly appreciate it. The requirement has been changed for which solution is not required this way. Thanks once again.

Comment: *WHERE  Question='Q1' AND Question='Q2'* That will never be true. `Question` cannot have two values at the same time.

Comment: @Leigh - you are quite right, the correct conjunction here is OR - I have edited it

Comment: Good. I suspect what they really wanted is userID's having *all* of the supplied question values (not *any*). ie Find users with a matching record for Q1 *and* Q2. In which case cha's suggestion of a `having` clause is probably closer to the mark. But that is just a guess. (Unfortunately the original question was not very clear.)

Answer (score 1):

Combine the Questions into a single string, separating by a comma, and making sure the values are not repeating, like this:

```
DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @NumberOfValues INT;
Set @SearchString = 'Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4';
Set @NumberOfValues = 4;
```

Then run this simple SQL statement:

```
SELECT Table1.* FROM 
Table1, (SELECT UserId, Count(DISTINCT Question) Cnt 
         From Table1 
         WHERE @SearchString LIKE '%' + RTRIM(Question) + '%' 
         GROUP BY UserID 
         HAVING Count(DISTINCT Question) = @NumberOfValues) AS T
WHERE Table1.UserId = T.UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PIVOT operator to create a pivot on the data causing Q1, Q2, Q3,... Q5 to display as columns with a count under each for each time a user answered that question.  Then query from the pivoted set with a filter Q1 and Q2 = 1.  You can run the following example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a31d/8

```
WITH UserQuestionsPivot AS
(
SELECT
  UserId,
  Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5
FROM 
(
SELECT
  UserId,
  1 AS Answered,
  Question
FROM UserQuestions
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Answered)
  FOR Question IN ([Q1], [Q2], [Q3], [Q4], [Q5])
) AS PivotTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM UserQuestionsPivot
WHERE Q1 = 1 AND Q2 = 1
```